# What is the relationship between Apache Tomcat and Apache Axis2 in the context of RESTful API and WSO2

Tags: java, rest, wso2, apache-axis

I know I want to build a RESTful api and use Angular on client side.  I am choosing between server technologies.  Apache Tomcat can do RESTful web services and could do for years now.  I was wondering if Axis2 is meant to be replacement for Tomcat.  Also I have been encouraged to incorporate WSO2 middleware which uses Axis2.  Ideally I'd like to use REST on Axis2 and then WSO2 middleware.

What is the relationship between Apache Tomcat and Apache Axis2 in the context of RESTful API and WSO2?  Does Axis2 run within Tomcat?

Comment: You really couldn't find the difference between Tomcat and Axis2 without asking about it on stackoverflow?

Comment: Google exists also in the world of Microsoft. Even Bing would know the differences. It's not very rewarding to answer questions which are essentially solvable with a few Google searches (and then the rest of the question is too broad to answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apache tomcat is an application server whereas Axis 2 is a Web Services engine.
So no, Axis2 is not meant to be replacement for Tomcat. An application built with Axis2 can be deployed on Tomcat or any other compatible Application Server(AS).
So yes, Axis 2 can run within Tomcat.

WSO2 is irrelevant to your question. Middleware includes Web servers, application servers, content management systems, and similar tools that support application development and delivery.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick description Apache Tomcat is a web server and more precisely a servlet container that allows you to handle HTTP resquest inside servlet.

Apache Axis 2 is a librairy that can handle web services (SOAP and RESTFull), it can run on a server such as Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

For REST API you can use WSO2 ESB or WSO2 API Management...also if you want to build a restful service you can create a webapp with JAX-RS and deploy it in WSO2 Application Server. As WSO2 Application server use Apache Tomcat you don´t require an Apache Tomcat Server.